How to use one field expression for multiple columns in polars
I have some data:
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "dt":pd.date_range("2024-12-01", periods=4, freq="D"),
    "A": {"value":[10, 10, 20, 30], "multiple":[1,2,0,0]},
    "B": {"value":[1, 2, 3, 4], "multiple":[0,5,5,0]},
})

I'd like to use:
result = df.with_columns(
    pl.exclude("dt").struct.with_fields(
        result=pl.field("value") * pl.field("multiple"),
    ).struct.with_fields(
        result2= pl.field("result") / 2
    ),
)

print(
    result.select(
        pl.exclude("dt").struct.unnest().name.prefix("<dont know how to determine col name>"),
    )
)

But it returns a different schema than I expected. I thought that for each column (exclude "dt") it would add fields for corresponding column.
I'd like to obtain this output without repetition in code (and without python list comprehension like *[pl.col(c).struct.with_fields(...) for c in wanted_cols]):
result = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("A").struct.with_fields(
        result=pl.field("value") * pl.field("multiple"),
    ).struct.with_fields(
        result2= pl.field("result") / 2
    ),
    pl.col("B").struct.with_fields(
        result=pl.field("value") * pl.field("multiple"),
    ).struct.with_fields(
        result2= pl.field("result") / 2
    )
)

print(
    result.select(
        pl.col("A").struct.unnest().name.prefix("A_"),
        pl.col("B").struct.unnest().name.prefix("B_"),
    )
)

Output is:
shape: (4, 8)
┌─────────┬────────────┬──────────┬───────────┬─────────┬────────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ A_value ┆ A_multiple ┆ A_result ┆ A_result2 ┆ B_value ┆ B_multiple ┆ B_result ┆ B_result2 │
│ ---     ┆ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ i64     ┆ i64        ┆ i64      ┆ f64       ┆ i64     ┆ i64        ┆ i64      ┆ f64       │
╞═════════╪════════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═════════╪════════════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 10      ┆ 1          ┆ 10       ┆ 5.0       ┆ 1       ┆ 0          ┆ 0        ┆ 0.0       │
│ 10      ┆ 2          ┆ 20       ┆ 10.0      ┆ 2       ┆ 5          ┆ 10       ┆ 5.0       │
│ 20      ┆ 0          ┆ 0        ┆ 0.0       ┆ 3       ┆ 5          ┆ 15       ┆ 7.5       │
│ 30      ┆ 0          ┆ 0        ┆ 0.0       ┆ 4       ┆ 0          ┆ 0        ┆ 0.0       │
└─────────┴────────────┴──────────┴───────────┴─────────┴────────────┴──────────┴───────────┘

Why the first implementation returns that wrong structs in schema than second implementation?
I've also tried flat df (without structs), cols like A_value, A_multiple, B_value, B_multiple and:
df.with_columns(
    (pl.selectors.ends_with("_value") * pl.selectors.ends_with("_multiple")).name.map(lambda c: c.split("_")[0] + "_result")
)

But expressions with different regexes are not implemented yet. Github polars issue 8282

I think the pl.exclude + with_fields behaviour is a bug: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/18461

I don't think it's currently possible without specifying column names. .name.prefix_fields() was added but you must pass a string. If it could infer the column name instead it would allow for: pl.exclude(...).struct.with_fields(...).name.prefix_fields() but there may be a technical reason why it doesn't do that. There is also an unnest/prefix mega-issue with some related discussion: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12353
